# how to style mentions-list in React Quill

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

I am using react-quill for mentioning users however I am not able to style mention list ,actually when I mention user, long list of user gets displayed on the screen which needs scrollbar to make it more presentable.how to achieve scrollbar in mention list in React-quill?
here is the code for better understanding.

```
  <div>
      <ReactQuill
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={editorHtml}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        bounds={".app"}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
    [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
    // [{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }],
    [{ align: [] }],
    ["link", "blockquote", "emoji"],
    ["clean"],
  ],
  clipboard: {
    // toggle to add extra line breaks when pasting HTML:
    matchVisual: false,
  },
  mention,
  "emoji-toolbar": true,
  "emoji-textarea": false,
  "emoji-shortname": true,
};


const formats = [
  "header",
  "font",
  "size",
  "bold",
  "italic",
  "underline",
  "strike",
  "blockquote",
  "list",
  "bullet",
  "indent",
  "link",
  "mention",
  "emoji",
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
.ql-mention-list-container {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```